# Google Vision API - Running Explicit Content Detection (Safe Search) Using a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm having trouble running an image from a URL through the Vision API's Safe Search/Explicit Content Detection. Python Samples can be found here:

https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/detect/detect.py

If I were to save the below in a python file - what is the best way to run it? I tried !python detect.py safe-search-uri http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/old-vw-bug-and-van.jpg but it's not working. Maybe I'm missing some of the code or running it the wrong way?

Sample Code from above github:

```
    from google.cloud import vision
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = vision.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.safe_search_detection(image=image)
    safe = response.safe_search_annotation

    # Names of likelihood from google.cloud.vision.enums
    likelihood_name = ('UNKNOWN', 'VERY_UNLIKELY', 'UNLIKELY', 'POSSIBLE',
                       'LIKELY', 'VERY_LIKELY')
    print('Safe search:')

    print('adult: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.adult]))
    print('medical: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.medical]))
    print('spoofed: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.spoof]))
    print('violence: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.violence]))
    print('racy: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.racy]))

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the whole error message?

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to run the file it doesn't return an error message. This is just the base code. I tried running detect.py safe-search-uri http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/old-vw-bug-and-van.jpg. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just executed the code snippet you included in your question, you are not passing the value `uri` to the code properly. You need to parse the arguments you are passing on your python command. You can do this by adding argparse.

```
from google.cloud import vision
import argparse

# Parse the options in this part #
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Safe search')
parser.add_argument(
    '--safe-search-uri',
    dest='uri'
    )
args = parser.parse_args()
uri = args.uri

# [START vision_safe_search_detection_gcs]
def detect_safe_search_uri(uri):
    """Detects unsafe features in the file located in Google Cloud Storage or
    on the Web."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = vision.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.safe_search_detection(image=image)
    safe = response.safe_search_annotation

    # Names of likelihood from google.cloud.vision.enums
    likelihood_name = ('UNKNOWN', 'VERY_UNLIKELY', 'UNLIKELY', 'POSSIBLE',
                       'LIKELY', 'VERY_LIKELY')
    print('Safe search:')

    print('adult: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.adult]))
    print('medical: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.medical]))
    print('spoofed: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.spoof]))
    print('violence: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.violence]))
    print('racy: {}'.format(likelihood_name[safe.racy]))

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))
# [END vision_safe_search_detection_gcs]

detect_safe_search_uri(uri)
```

Testing using command `!python detect.py --safe-search-uri http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/old-vw-bug-and-van.jpg` :
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ricco!!

Comment: Can it detect content if you provide it with an image as object instead of from a directory?